# Why 'break' is not working in array_walk php

Tags: php, loops, break

Please see my code, i am almost stuck in this, Why the break inside the array_walk not breaking...

```
$bool=array_walk($_POST, 'check_empty');

function check_empty($item, $key)
{               
        $bool=(isset($item) && $item != "") ? 1: 0 ;

         if(!$bool)
         {
         //return 0;
         break;
         }

        return $bool;
}
```

Comment: Because you are returning before break.

Comment: you have written return. After return it will not execute. No need of break.

Comment: What is it supposed to `break`?

Answer (score 3):

It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, but `break` is a control structure that exits only **true loops** (`for`, `foreach`, `while` and `do-while`) and **switch** structures.

`array_walk` is iterative but not a loop in the true sense.

You can't 'break' (to use the terminology) from an array walk callback; it is invoked on each element of the array as a means to update or otherwise modify each element, and I can't imagine a use case where you'd want to terminate this during it.

Comment: Actually i am writing a common logic for handling $_POST array in php. if any null value in the array, break off. Do you have any other logic?

Comment: How do you mean "break off" - stop executing the script and report an error to the user?

Comment: Exit from the loop ..!!

Comment: You need to rethink your approach here. It would make no sense to attempt to exit from an array walk callback. The whole point of it is that the callback is called on EVERY element in the array. If you want to exit the loop, use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Your `break` is not working, because you're returning a value right before it - so the line with `break` is never executed.

If you're trying to remove all empty values from the array, try `array_filter($array)`.

Comment: Actually i am writing a common logic for handling $_POST array in php. if any null value in the array, break off. Do you have any other logic?